# Better way to store user access token in angular applications

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, caching

What is the best way of storing the user token for accessing my app? I've seen an online Angular course where he explains how to store user id and access token in the local storage but i see risks in doing this. It's easy to gather the token for another user who wants to log in as the victim, so what's the best way of doing it securely?

Thank you in advice

I've not tried anything yet but there must be another solution. Or maybe is it the best way?